# Hacker rank string separated challenge

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to solve a hacker rank challenge:
Given a string, s , of length n that is indexed from 0 to n-1 , print its even-indexed and odd-indexed characters as 2 space-separated strings. on a single line (see the Sample below for more detail)
link: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop/problem

Error:
[image]

for example:
The input "adbecf" should output "abc def"

When I run python Visualizer my code seem to have the correct output.. but on hacker rank it's saying I have the wrong answer. Does anyone know what might be wrong with my code.

This is the code I tried -

```
class OddEven:

   def __init__(self, input_statement):
       self.user_input = input_statement
   def user_list(self):
       main_list = list(user_input)
       
       even = []
       odd = []
       space = [" "]
       
       
       for i in range(len(main_list)):
           if (i%2) == 0:
               even.append(main_list[i])
           else:
               odd.append(main_list[i])
       full_string = even + space + odd
       return(full_string)
       
   def listToString(self):
       my_string = self.user_list()
       return(''.join(my_string))
       
       
       

if __name__ == "__main__":
   user_input = str(input ())
   p = OddEven(user_input)
   print(p.listToString())
```

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the error message you get, as well as a link to the problem so we can see how your code is being tested. I don't see any reason right now why you'd need to make an entire class for something this simple, just use string slicing: `print(s[0::2], s[1::2])`.

Comment: Isn't it 2 space-separated strings?

Comment: When you run the code, does it ask for user input?

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/30-review-loop/problem

Comment: Your program is not correct because you are not reading all the input required. The first input is supposed to be the number of test cases, then subsequent inputs are the strings. Your program is just reading the number of test cases and does something with that, then exits.

Also `main_list = list(user_input)`, this is using the global `user_input`, not the one inside your class (`self.user_input`). Just saw the error you are getting which confirms what I just said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, input is always string, you don't need to convert it here.

```
user_input = str(input())
```

Each line is provided to you as separate input. Number of strings equal to num in the first line. In this case 2, so...

```
count = input()
for s in range(int(count)):
    ...
```

`user_input` variable inside `user_list` function should be accessed as `self.user_input`, it's a property of an object, which you pass to function as `self`.

Also you can iterate over list directly.

Here:

```
full_string = even + space + odd
```

you're trying to concatenate list, which is not a good idea, you'll still get a list.
You can join list with separating them with some string using `join` string method.

```
' '.join(list1, list2, ..., listN)
```

It's better do define `odd` and `even` as empty strings.
And then join them the using concatenation (+).

Here:

```
if (i%2) == 0
```

you don't have to compare with 0. Python will evaluate what's to the right from condition as True or False. So:

```
if i % 2:
    ...
```

There is simpler solution:

```
def divide(self):
    odd = even = ''
    
    for i, c in enumerate(self.user_input):
        if i % 2:
            odd += c
        else:
            even += c
    return even + ' ' + odd
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple code for this problem:)

```
T=int(input())
for i in range(0,T):
    S=input()
    print(S[0::2],S[1::2])
```